# Java Applet: Why Is This Animation So Quick and How Can I Make It Slower

Tags: java, animation, applet

I am working on a Java Applet and just for bonus points, I wanted to see if I could animate the trajectory of what I made. I got it `draw()` function to animate how I wanted it to, but the animation is really quick and you can barely see it. I tried increasing the milliseconds in the threaded process, but it made no difference. Hopefully my question makes sense. I included my code below.

```
public class Slinkey extends Applet implements Runnable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4803949557086825455L;
private Thread animation; 
private boolean stopSlinky; 

@Override
public void start() {
    stopSlinky = false;
    animation = new Thread(this);
    animation.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) { // This can probably be ignored.
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int w = 100;
    int h = 100;
    int k = 0;
    int otherX = 0;
    double xpos = 0, ypos = 10;

    System.out.println(xpos + " " + ypos);

    Ellipse2D.Double c1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(ypos, ypos, w, h);


    for (k = 0; k < 155; k += 5) {
        xpos = x + k;
        ypos = getYStart(xpos); 

        System.out.println(xpos + " " + ypos);

        c1.setFrame(xpos, ypos, w, h); // (10, 10) (1325, 650)
        g2.draw(c1);
    }


    for (int i = 160; i < 775; i++) {
        xpos = x + i;
        otherX++; 
        ypos = getYMain(otherX);

        if (ypos < 652) {
            System.out.println("Y Coordinate: " + xpos + " " + ypos);
            c1.setFrame(xpos, ypos, w, h);
            g2.draw(c1);
        }
    }


    for (int j = 775; j < 1325; j++) {
        xpos = x + j; 
        otherX++; 
        ypos = (0.7) * (getYMain(otherX - 500) + 400);

        if (ypos < 652) {
            System.out.println("Y Coordinate: " + xpos + " " + ypos);
            c1.setFrame(xpos, ypos, w, h);
            g2.draw(c1);
        }
    }   
}
public static double getYStart(double x) {
    return (0.029) * (Math.pow(x - 10, 2) + 10);
}

public static double getYMain(double x) {
    return ((0.005) * Math.pow(x - 350, 2) + 300);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        if (stopSlinky) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
}

public void stop() {
    stopSlinky = true; 
    animation = null;
}
```

}

(I know the code is very messy. I'm working on organizing it.)

Comment: Applets are dead are no longer supported, it's time to move on. Your primary issue comes down to the fact that you don't understand how the painting process works. Start by looking at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Comment: Swing is also not thread safe (and is single threaded) so you will want to be careful how you update the UI or the state that the UI depends on.  The simple solution is to use a Swing `Timer`, see [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).  This kind of question gets asked on the time and there are plenty of examples floating around.  Animation in Swing is also a little bit of black magic, so I would recommend you spend you time more productively and look towards using JavaFX instead

Comment: For what it's worth, `Applet` is not double buffered, so even if you could fix the above issues to make it work, it would suffer from flickering, which would better solved using Swing based components instead - or just using JavaFX